# Displaying error message from 404 (Not Found) and 401 (Unauthorized) responses to frontend using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

BACKEND - added a message in status return but for some reason I can only access content inside response object when status is 200.

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {

  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password

  User.findOne({
    where: {
      username: username
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({message: "User Not Found"});
      }

      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
        password,
        user.password
      );

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          accessToken: null,
          message: "Invalid Password!"
        });
      }

      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400
      });

      var authorities = [];
      user.getRoles().then(roles => {
        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          authorities.push("ROLE_" + roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
        }
        res.status(200).send({
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          roles: authorities,
          accessToken: token
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message }); 
    });

};
```

FRONTEND - here I want to display "User Not Found" or "Invalid password" depending on which status the server returns.

```
    function Login() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    var [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const login = () => {
        const data = { username: username, password: password }
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", data).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 404) {
            setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
            setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
        } else {
            console.log(response.data)
        }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="loginContainer">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(event) => {
                    setUsername(event.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(event) => {
                    setPassword(event.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
            <p>{loginStatus}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what difficulty are you facing

Comment: well it manages to console.log(response.data) when status is 200 
when i enter wrong username and password in my login form the server returns error 404 like it should but i want it to return 404 and display in <p>{loginStatus}</p> "User not found" at the same time @abhipatil

Answer (score 0):

Axios throws an error when the status code is not in the `2xx` range.

That essentially means that if your server returns a `401` or a `404`, the `then` block on your client's Axios call will never run.

You'll need to handle these errors in the `catch` block. Example below.

```js
const login = () => {
  const data = { username: username, password: password }
  axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", data).then((response) => {
    // Only 2xx responses come here...
    console.log(response.data)
  }).catch(e => {
    // All errors (4xx, 5xx) come here...
    setLoginStatus(e.response.data.message)
  })
}
```